# JPanel and ActionLister not working

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I could use two ActionLister to perform the same action but I use the implement to make the code condense but it just doesnt work.
When I choose b1, there is no text on the textfield.

```
public Radio_Button() {
        setSize(600, 400);
        panel = new JPanel();
        tf = new JTextField("                ");
        group = new ButtonGroup();
        b1 = new JRadioButton("1");
        b2 = new JRadioButton("2");
        b1.setActionCommand("you choose one");
        b2.setActionCommand("you choose two");
        group.add(b1);
        group.add(b2);
        panel.add(b1);
        panel.add(b2);
        panel.add(tf);
        add(panel);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        tf.setText(e.getActionCommand());

    }
}
```

Comment: [How to write a ActionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) might be a better resource

Comment: First time I see this site. Thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget to register a listener for the radio buttons.

Add this after `setActionCommand()`.

```
b1.addActionListener(this);
b2.addActionListener(this);
```

In case you have different buttons

```
 JButton button1 = new JButton("Some Text");
 JButton button2 = new JButton("Some Other Text");

  button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "I was clicked !");
        } });

   button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Second button was clicked!");
        } });
```

Comment: Thx! I thought this is not needed. Can I also ask, if I have other different buttons in the panel but I want them to show a pop-up window when I press them. Can I also use it in this implemented ActionLister or I would have to make one for them?

Comment: I would suggest you to make one for them.